# How can I detect whether a template argument is a noexcept function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I have function to generate a lambda that acts as a wrapper to a function I can invoke later:

```
template <typename F, typename... FArgs>
auto make_lambda( F&& f, FArgs&&... f_args )
{
    return [&] () -> std::result_of_t<F( FArgs... )>
    {
        return std::forward<F>( f )( std::forward<FArgs>( f_args )... );
    };
}
```

I'd like to make the returned lambda `noexcept` when argument `f` is `noexcept`, so my function's return would look like this:

```
return [&] () noexcept( is_noexcept<decltype( f )>::value )
    -> std::result_of_t<F( FArgs... )>
{
    return std::forward<F>( f )( std::forward<FArgs>( f_args )... );
};
```

My attempt:

```
#include <type_traits>

void f() {}
void g() noexcept {}

template <typename F, typename... Args>
struct is_noexcept : std::false_type {};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
struct is_noexcept<F( Args... ) noexcept> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    bool constexpr func_test_a{ is_noexcept<decltype( f )>::value }; // true
    bool constexpr func_test_b{ is_noexcept<decltype( g )>::value }; // true
}
```

However, the test always returns `true`. What am I missing? Can anyone provide a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`noexcept` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept), which takes an expression and produces `true` if that expression is `noexcept`.

Untested, but this might work for your use case.

```
return [&] () noexcept(noexcept(std::forward<F>( f )( std::forward<FArgs>( f_args )... )))
    -> std::result_of_t<F( FArgs... )>
{
    return std::forward<F>( f )( std::forward<FArgs>( f_args )... );
};
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it still returns `true` for `f()` and `g()`.

Comment: As noted in my answer, this will be a valid answer in C++17.

Comment: **Heavily** tested with gcc 7.3.1 and clang 5.0.2. `noexcept` given any variation of a compile-time instanced type (`std::declval`, `std::forward`, simply `f`) rather than an _expression_ in either C++11 or C++14 always results in `false`. gcc even warns about it. Again, **heavily** tested. Weirdly, the `std::is_nothrow_destructible` implementation in my `/usr/include/c++/type_traits` relies on something like `std::integral_constant<bool, noexcept(declval<T>().~T())>`, but I think that's something of a grey area expression-wise (still confusing though).

Answer (score 13):

From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

> The noexcept-specification is not a part of the function type. (until
>   C++17).

Currently, template deduction will not produce the correct results since the `noexcept` specifier is not part of a function's type; template type deduction will not work until C++17. My way of detecting whether a function is `noexcept` will be valid in C++17 as will [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589752/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-template-argument-is-a-noexcept-function/33589779#33589779)'s way.