# SFINAE and noexcept specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14, sfinae

Does an expression in `noexcept` specifier's parentheses participate in SFINAE during overload resolution of function templates?

I want to make an wrapper for aggregates and want the `std::is_constructible` predicate to work properly for it:

```
template< typename type >
struct embrace
    : type
{

    template< typename ...arguments >
    embrace(arguments &&... _arguments) noexcept(noexcept(type{std::forward< arguments >(_arguments)...}))
        : type{std::forward< arguments >(_arguments)...} // braces 
    { ; }

};

int
main()
{
    struct S { int i; double j; }; // aggregate
    using E = embrace< S >;
    E b(1, 1.0); // "parentheses"-constructible => can be used as usual types
    b.i = 1; b.j = 2.0; // accessible
    static_assert(std::is_constructible< E, int, double >{});
    static_assert(std::is_constructible< E, struct B >{}); // want hard error here
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But my attempt to use `noexcept` operator inside `noexcept` specification to enable SFINAE is failed, and the templated constructor accepts everything passed to it. How can the constructor be restricted?

It is not permitted by the Standard to specialize any predicates from `<type_traits>`. How to deal with c-tors that accepts variadic template parameter packs and SFINAE in general? Is there an impasse and inherent language flaw?

Comment: What compiler is this?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod [clang 3.7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46c26922bef7a4f7)

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod *g++* gives early hard error (in c-tor itself and not a SFINAE).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SFINAE simply doesn't apply to *exception-specification*s, whether or not `noexcept` is part of the function type.

See the note in [temp.deduct]/7:

> The substitution occurs in all types and expressions that are used in
>   the function type and in template parameter declarations. The
>   expressions include not only constant expressions such as those that
>   appear in array bounds or as nontype template arguments but also
>   general expressions (i.e., non-constant expressions) inside sizeof,
>   decltype, and other contexts that allow non-constant expressions. The
>   substitution proceeds in lexical order and stops when a condition that
>   causes deduction to fail is encountered. [ *Note*: The equivalent
>   substitution in exception specifications is done only when the
>   *exception-specification* is instantiated, at which point a program is ill-formed if the substitution results in an invalid type or
>   expression. —*end note* ]

P0012R1 [didn't change anything](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/6e75f2d588a4b1b0c220eb8eec4b9ad8cb6107f3) in this respect.

Piotr's answer covers the fix for your code.

Comment: Do you want to say `C++17` will not bring something new in this respect?

Comment: @Orient P0012R1 is the "add exception specifications to type system" paper, and it didn't change anything w/r/t SFINAE on exception specifications. It's premature to say C++17 will not do X when we are still two years away.

Answer (score 4):

> *How can the constructor be restricted?*

```
#include <utility>

template <typename type>
struct embrace : type
{
    template <typename... arguments
            , typename = decltype(type{std::declval<arguments>()...})>
    embrace(arguments&&... _arguments)
        noexcept(noexcept(type{std::forward<arguments>(_arguments)...}))
        : type{std::forward<arguments>(_arguments)...}
    {
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dt30TcFZdDKrtLqU)

(or shorter):

```
#include <utility>

template <typename type>
struct embrace : type
{
    template <typename... arguments
            , bool NoExcept = noexcept(type{std::declval<arguments>()...})>
    constexpr
    embrace(arguments&&... _arguments)
        noexcept(NoExcept)
        : type{std::forward<arguments>(_arguments)...}
    {
    }
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/s9HK3mkYjHf0vxqr)

Comment: I think non-trailing template parameter pack is not allowed. Can you elucidate this point?

Comment: Either way it is perfect solution.

Comment: @Orient It's allowed if it can be deduced. A parameter pack must be at the end only for primary class templates and alias templates

Comment: Question: for demo 2, I'm not familiar with placing constexpr after the template params. What does that do and why do you need it?

Answer (score 2):

> Does an expression in noexcept specifier's parentheses participate in
>   SFINAE during overload resolution of function templates?

It doesn't participate in template deduction because the `noexcept` specifier is not part of a function's type.

> The noexcept-specification is not a part of the function type. (until
>   C++17)

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec)

Therefore, when your template parameter `type` is deduced, `noexcept` is not part of the deduced type. Your compiler seems to return `true` for any type which is why you aren't able to detect whether it is `noexcept` or not; that is why everything is accepted.

I ran into the same issue. You can check my question/answer here:

[How can I detect whether a template argument is a noexcept function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589752/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-template-argument-is-a-noexcept-function/33590539#33590539)

Basically, your only option is to wait for a C++17 compliant compiler.

Comment: Seems `-std=gnu++1z` currently not allows one to use the mentioned in answer. Nor in `clang++` neither in `g++`.

Comment: Why `g++`'s and `clang++`'s compilers behaviour differs?

Comment: @Orient It depends on how compliant they are with C++17, otherwise the `noexcept` part will not be available to you from the deduced type.

Comment: That's a different and distinct issue.