# sfinae away a destructor

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, sfinae

I am implementing something very similar to `std::vector` but uses array on the stack instead of memory allocation.

The d-tor calls a function that uses SFINAE.

- If `value_type` is POD the function have empty body.
- If `value_type` is normal class such `std::string`, the function have a body and destroy all the data properly.

Now, I want to be able to use this new `std::vector` as `constexpr`. However even the c-tor is declared `constexpr`, the code does not compiles because the class have non trivial d-tor.

Here is small part of the code:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
class SmallVector{
    constexpr SmallVector() = default;

    ~SmallVector(){
        destructAll_<value_type>();
    }

    // ...

    template<typename X>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_destructible<X>::value == true>::type
    destructAll_() noexcept{
    }

};
```

Is there anything I can do to make class be `constexpr` if `value_type` is POD and keeping functionality for non POD data types.
(Not at the same time of course)

Comment: I would instead inherit from `SmallVectorImpl<T, SIZE, is_trivially_destructible<T>::value>` which will have a main definition and a specialization for trivially destructible types. The only difference between the two being the destructor.

Comment: my idea is similar - one read only base class and all mutating methods in two inherited versions.

Can you pls make an answer with your idea too, because I do not see how third template "component" helps. do you mean to inherit from two base classes?

Comment: How similar to `std::vector` can such a type be, really? Are you rather reimplementing `std::array`? Orrrr is it a vector with a huge auto-storage array and lots of placement new? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I assume rewriting vector + stack-backed-pool-allocator

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - is academical purpose. and is like array with push back and lots of placement new.

Comment: try using if constexpr?

Comment: @ZFY Check My answer of 'if constexpr'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## until C+20

Unfortunately, there is no way to enable/disable destructor with SFINAE, <del>nor with future concepts</del>. That is because destructos:

- can't be templated
- can't have arguments
- can't have a return type

What you can do is specialize whole class, or better yet, create a base class that contains only the construct/destruct and basic access and specialize that.

```
template <class T, class Enable = void>
struct X {
    ~X() {}
};

template <class T>
struct X<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod<T>::value>> {
};

static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<X<int>>::value);
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_destructible<X<std::vector<int>>>::value);
```

## C++ 20

As far as I can tell you can constraint a destructor and get exactly what you want in a very simple and elegant solution:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
class SmallVector{
public:
    constexpr SmallVector() = default;

    ~SmallVector() requires std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T> = default;

    ~SmallVector()
    {   
    }
};

static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<SmallVector<int, 4>>);
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_destructible_v<SmallVector<std::string, 4>>);
```

However this is a brand new feature and there have been some changes lately (e.g. see [Disable non-templated methods with concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381851/disable-non-templated-methods-with-concepts)) and the compiler support is still sketchy. gcc compiles this just fine, while clang is confused by the fact that there are two definitions of the destructor [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/m744W6)

Comment: I had an idea to use SFINAE inside `noexcept` specifier of the destructor, but SFINAE [does not apply there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665208/sfinae-and-noexcept-specifier/33667546#33667546), unfortunately.

Answer (score -3):

The example of `if constexpr` in destructor. (C++17 required)

```cpp
template<typename Tp, typename TLock>
struct LockedPtr {
private:
    Tp   *m_ptr;
    TLock *m_lk;
    void prelock(std::mutex *mtx) { mtx->lock(); }
    void prelock(std::atomic_flag *atom) { while(atom->test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)); }

public:
    LockedPtr(Tp *ptr, TLock *mtx)
    : m_ptr(ptr), m_lk(mtx) {
        prelock(mtx); 
    }

    ~LockedPtr() {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<TLock, std::mutex>)
            ((std::mutex *)m_lk)->unlock();
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<TLock, std::atomic_flag>)
            ((std::atomic_flag *)m_lk)->clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
```

These code is the part of RAII locked smart pointer, to adopt to normal `std::mutex` and spinlock by `std::atomic_flag`.

- Using function overload to match different type in constructor.
- Match type by `if constexpr` and make something unconvertable to pointer in destructor.

Comment: I think you might have posted to the wrong question?

Comment: See the example of   ~LockedPtr(), to match type by if constexpr and make something unconvertable to pointer

Comment: I agree that OP could've used `if constexpr` in the destructor, but it's very confusing to post an big unrelated class just to demonstrate it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for your advise, the unnecessary code has removed.