# Providing a method only in a partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I have class `Matrix` and i want a specialized method of `len()` if `R = 3` and `C = 1`.
I would like to have solution with the standard library.
Inheritance is not a solution because it wont work on the base class too.

Normal template specialization like

```cpp
template<class T>
class Matrix<T, 3, 1> {
public:
    T len() const {return 3;}
};
```

would force me to implement all other `Matrix<T, R, C>` methodes and stuff too. (?)

Ideas:

- std::enable_if
- constexpr
- ...

```cpp
#include <vector>

template<class T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class Matrix {
private:
    std::vector <T> data;
public:
    T len() const;
};
```

A dirty solution would be:

```cpp
template<class T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
T Matrix<T, R, C>::len() const {
    if constexpr (R == 3 && C == 1) {
        return 3;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("len not available");
}
```

Comment: @Evg: He wants a matrix of one row to be treated like a vector and therefore have vector functionality like computing the length.

Comment: *"Normal template specialization [..] would force me to implement all other `Matrix<T, R, C>` methods and stuff too."* If you split base `Matrix` implementation and customizable part, you should be avoid duplication.

Comment: C++20 would have `requires`.

Comment: `static_assert(R ==3 && C == 1);` seems better than throw.

Comment: @NicolBolas, why `3` then? And why `len()` returns T?

Comment: Why return type of `len` is `T` ?

Comment: @Evg: A vector of floats should have a length in floats. Also, it's not especially relevant why this needs to be restricted to a 3 column vector; the question is how to do it.

Comment: If you need the interface to be different as well, the only way is to partial specialize the template class itself. Otherwise you could use SFINAE to enable/disable the functions as needed. Better than `static_assert` because the error would be at call site.

Comment: for c++20 requires: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381851/disable-non-templated-methods-with-concepts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution using [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

```cpp
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if
#include <vector>      // std::vector

template <class T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class Matrix {
 private:
  std::vector<T> data;

 public:
  template <std::size_t C_ = C, typename = std::enable_if_t<C_ == 1>>
  std::size_t len() const {
    double res = 0;
    for (const auto& x : data) {
      res += std::pow(x, 2);
    }
    return std::sqrt(res);
  }

};
```

Alternative out-of-line definition:

```cpp
template <class T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class Matrix {
 private:
  std::vector<T> data;

 public:
  template <std::size_t R_ = R,
            std::size_t C_ = C,
            typename E1 = std::enable_if_t<R_ == 3>,
            typename E2 = std::enable_if_t<C_ == 1>>
  double len() const;
};

template <class T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
template <std::size_t R_, std::size_t C_, typename E1, typename E2>
double Matrix<T, R, C>::len() const {
  double res = 0;
  for (const auto& x : data) {
    res += std::pow(x, 2);
  }
  return std::sqrt(res);
}
```

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // std::cout, std::endl

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  Matrix<double, 3, 1> vec;
  std::cout << "vec length: " << vec.len() << std::endl;
  // output: vec length: 3

  // Matrix<double, 3, 3> mat;
  // std::cout << "mat length: " << mat.len() << std::endl; // does not compile

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to declare it out of line? `template<class T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
template<std::size_t R_ = R, typename = std::enable_if_t<R_ == 3>, std::size_t C_ = C, typename = std::enable_if_t<C_ == 1>>
T Matrix<T, R, C>::len() const {
    return std::sqrt(std::pow(this->v(0), 2) + std::pow(this->v(1), 2) + std::pow(this->v(2), 2));
}` seems not to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

Explanation inline as comments:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, int R, int C>
struct Matrix;

namespace MatrixOperations
{
    // default handling is to prevent compilation
    template<class Mat>
    auto len(Mat const&) -> void = delete;

    // special case for a 3,1 matrix
    template<class T>
    auto len(Matrix<T, 3, 1> const&) -> T
    {
        return T(3);
    }
};

template<class T, int R, int C>
struct Matrix
{
    // ForceDeduce is a defaulted type.
    // The argument of this type is defaulted
    // It's purpose is to ensure that this function is not actually compiled until it is used
    // This will prevent the call to MatrixOperations::len producing an error unless this function
    // is called
    template<class ForceDeduce = int*>
    T len(ForceDeduce = nullptr) const
    {
        return MatrixOperations::len(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Matrix <int, 3, 1> m31;
    std::cout << m31.len() << std::endl;

    Matrix <int, 3, 2> m32;
// fails to compile
//    std::cout << m32.len() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Once you go to all the trouble of making `Matrix::len` a template, why not make it SFINAE-friendly (and do without the namespace versions)?