# Constraining template parameters

Tags: c++, sfinae, c++-concepts, static-assert

Suppose I have a class template, `Angle<T>`, and I want to constrain instantiation to `T`s that are floating point types.

The SFINAE approach:

```
template <typename T,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> = true>
struct Angle { T m_radians; };
```

C++20 gives us concepts:

```
template <std::floating_point T>
struct Angle { T m_radians; };
```

Alternatively, I could constrain the type with `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Angle {
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point_v<T>,
                  "Angle<T> works only with floating point types.");
    T m_radians;
};
```

**Question:**  Are there constraints I could place on template parameters with concepts/`requires` that I couldn't do with `<type_traits>`/`static_assert`?

[I'm *not* asking for opinions about which technique is better.  Also, I understand that concepts, like `enable_if`, can leverage SFINAE to eliminate overloads and specializations from consideration during resolution, which you cannot do with `static_assert`.  My question is strictly about constraints.]

Comment: Everything that concepts can do can be done without concepts, in some way, varying anywhere between little to a lot of extra work.

Comment: There are some things that can be achieved in a clearer way like having different destructors [sfinae away a destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094871) (and this external article [C++20 Concepts: Subsumption rules](https://andreasfertig.blog/2020/09/cpp20-concepts-subsumption-rules/)). So you can do things with concepts that you can't do directly with SFINAE, but you can still achieve the same using SFINAE with some additional work.

Comment: @t.niese I would call that a non constraint issue, which the OP wants to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

They are all capable of doing Turing-complete computation on the passed in types and accepting an arbitrary subset, and have access to the same information about each type.

None is stronger or weaker.

Comment: Is that true?  With concepts, I can write `requires (T x) { x.foo(); }` to ensure `T` is a class type with an invokable `foo` member.  Can I use `static_assert` and `<type_traits>` to make the same check?

Comment: @adrian yes, it is just more complicated.  Like a lot more complicated.  I am unaware of anything that concepts provides that cannot be mimiced, outside of sfinae improvements and template instantiation limitations, which you explicitly said you don't care about.  And regardless, you can use a concept as a constexpr bool in a static assert.