# How to support an aggregates into the STL or STL-like library

Tags: c++, stl, containers, aggregate, c++17

How to introduce the support of aggregate-initialization for construction of them properly in (e.g.) STL containers? I mean something like:

```
struct A { int i; char c; };
std::list< A > l; // empty
l.insert(std::memberwise, 1, '2');
// <=> l.insert({1, '2'});
```

`std::memberwise` is a possible tag, like already existent in STL `std::piecewise_construct`, `std::allocator_arg` etc.

Is it theoretically possible to extend STL containers in such a way? Is there a best way ("STL-way") to do this? How it might look like?

The question is about an interface design and about possibility of (internal) implementation (not details).

I sure containers uses something like `::new (static_cast< void * >(pstorage) value_type(std::forward< Args >(args)...);` internally. I sure, it would breaking change to replace brackets with braces. Because of non-narrowing, e.g.

#### ADDITIONALLY

Generally `l.insert({1, '2'});` mentioned in comments can lead to excessive move of `value_type`. Very likely this step would be optimized out by any modern compiler, but either way there are excessive curly brackets.

Comment: In your specific case, `l.insert({1, '2'});` works in C++11.

Comment: @Chad yes, AFAIK, but `l.emplace{,_back}(1, '2');` - not.

Comment: @Orient You might want to consider adding a constructor for your struct that initializes i and c. For the "emplace" container functions to construct the object in-place you need this as far as I know. If you do an `emplace` or `emplace_back` via aggregate initialization it actually makes an object and then copies it into the struct.

Comment: @RyanP For generic code it is impossible. There is no `std::is_aggregate` to detect aggregates to wrap them into the [aggregate wrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665208/sfinae-and-noexcept-specifier).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `emplace`-style construction. Standard library containers forward such construction to `allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct<T>`, which is expected to be a variadic function. If `Alloc` has no `construct` member function, then `allocator_traits::construct` will simply use placement new with `()` initialization syntax.

Obviously that doesn't allow you to do aggregate initialization through `emplace`. However, you can effectively implement [the solution suggested by LWG 2089](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2089) by providing your own allocator, perhaps derived from `std::allocator`, which has its own `construct` method. Your `construct` should only use `new(p) T(...)` if the `is_constructible<T, ...>::value` is true. If it isn't, then you use `new(p) T{...}`.

In C++17, this is actually not hard to write:

```
template< class U, class... Args >
void construct( U* p, Args&&... args )
{
    if constexpr(std::is_constructible_v<U, Args...>)
        ::new((void*)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    else
        ::new((void*)p) U{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

Comment: Really I don't need poor `std::initializer_list` (due to it can't move), so the solution seems perfect for me. Thank you.

Comment: Is it intentioanlly `operator new` is not global and `operator new` applied to non-`void` pointer? Is this exactly correct using of `operator new` overloading into the `Allocator::construct`?

Comment: In *Notes* [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new): `the code that wants to ensure that the true placement new is called (e.g. std::allocator::construct), must use ::new and also cast the pointer to void`.

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct) also states which one should be used for member function template `construct`.